# Consuming service in jar using webservice

Tags: web-services, rest

I have services in a jar file created by spring mvc.
My question is how to consume this services through rest api in an other spring boot project .
Any help is highly appreciate.

my AppConfig :

```
package com.Taco;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"org.DAO","org.Service"})
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Declare your jar as a dependency in your other spring project.
2. In config class declare your service in `@ComponentScan`

Comment: Thank you for your reputation,My problem how to scan the appConfig class in the project

Comment: can you send your appConfig  class !

Comment: I edited my question by adding AppConfig class, Thank you for your help